# Defining an array(C) in Julia by appending array B to array A without changing the values of the array A

Tags: arrays, julia

I have two arrays `A` and `B`. Let's say `A=[1,2,3]` and `B=[4,5,6]`. I want to define a third array `C = append!(A,B)`. The problem is this also changes `A` to be `A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append!` pushes the elements of the second collection to the first one, modifying it, to just concatenate them, use `vcat`:

```
C = vcat(A, B)
```

Or you can use `;` to build a new array from the contents of `A` and `B`:

```
C = [A ; B]
```

Comment: Maybe worth knowing that the bracket with a semicolon is just syntax for `vcat`, as you can check with `Meta.@lower [a; b]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[4,5,6]

C=A
append!(C,B)
```

Then C = [1,2,3,4,5,6] and B = [4,5,6]. But unfortunately, A = [1,2,3,4,5,6].

The problem is `C=A`, which makes A and C the same in every way, except for the variable name. Unfortunately, changes to C then also change A, because they occupy the same area of memory, they have the same address.

What you have to do is to `copy` A to C, before appending B. Then C and A have the same data, before B is appended, but they are separate things. Changing C no longer changes A.

```
 A = [1,2,3]
 B = [4,5,6]

 C=copy(A)
 append!(C,B)
```

Then C = [1,2,3,4,5,6] and B = [4,5,6]. And, A = [1,2,3].